# update a table from another table using oracle db

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to update one table from another one:
I can do the update with the MySQL sgbd:

```
update product pr ,  provider p 
set pr.provider_name = p.name 
where p.provider_id = pr.provider_id ;
```

but when I try to do it with oracle :
I tried this query for oracle

```
UPDATE pr 
SET pr.provider_name = p.name 
FROM product pr 
INNER JOIN provider p ON p.provider_id = pr.provider_id  ;
```

I get this error:

```
Error Code: 933, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

What's wrong with my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
UPDATE product
SET provider_name = (
    SELECT p.name 
    FROM provider p 
    WHERE p.provider_id = product.provider_id
);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE product prod SET prod.provider_name = (SELECT prov.name
                                                FROM provider prov 
                                               WHERE prod.provider_id = prov.provider_id)
```